# maven SNAPSHOT workings

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, maven, maven-plugin

Currently maven Snapshots are created whenever a new build is ran. I was hoping if there is syntax that only stamps them when there is SCM change in that build or code in a particular jar has changed.

Your ideas and thoughts would be appreciated.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, only your SCM knows if there's been a change.  So the logic would have to check the SCM whether there's been a change, and only build if there has been

Comment: I agree but the SNAPSHOT should only be updated when a new change in the code occurs in only the particular jar that has changes. as supposed to the entire list of jar files in that build. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: Oh, I see.  That's very interesting and definitely useful.  No need to build `foo-1.2.jar` just because `dependency-2.0-SNAPSHOT` is updated.

I'm pretty sure Maven doesn't support this, but if you submit an issue to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG it might get some attention.